# Trouble activating boxes connected to each dot in a map

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python with selenium to activate each box connected to each dot available on the map in a webpage but unfortunately I can't do that with my script. I'cant get any idea to move on. Hope somebody will guide me to the right direction.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://acwi.gov/monitoring/vm/programs/vm_map.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//g[@id='NWQMC_VM_directory_June2016_3915_0_layer']"):
    item.find_element_by_xpath(".//circle[@fill='rgb(237, 81, 81)']").click()

driver.quit()
```

Elements within the map in which a single dot is given below. It's huge so I've curtailed for a single dot:

```
<circle fill="rgb(237, 81, 81)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgb(153, 153, 153)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="478" cy="306" r="4" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"></circle>
```

Image of some activated dot:
[image_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUJBL.jpg)

Comment: what data are you hoping to scrape? the contents of all the pop up boxes?

Comment: Thanks sir Dan-Dev, for your comment. Any of them will do? I just wanted to know the process. This is totally new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it may need tweaking but it opens the map in a new, large window zooms out then clicks on each dot in order stepping through each next button if displayed. The reason it opens a new large window and zooms out is to prevent the page reloading and elements becoming stale.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep


def recurse():
    sleep(3)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".titleButton.next")
    if elem.is_displayed():
        elem.click()
        sleep(3)
        scrape()
        recurse()


def scrape():
    pass


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1615, 924) # Make the window size as large as possible to prevent re-rendering and stale elements.
driver.get("https://acwi.gov/monitoring/vm/programs/vm_map.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
driver.get(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe").get_attribute("src")) # Get a full window to prevent re-rendering and stale elements.
sleep(15) # Wait for re-rendering to prevent stale elements.

zoom = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mapDiv_zoom_slider']/div[2]")
zoom.click()  # Zoom out to prevent re-rendering and stale elements.
for item in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('circle'):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click().perform()
    scrape()
    recurse()
    sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks sir Dan-Dev, for your effective answer.